# Tell Grails to use My Own RoleVoter

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've implemented my own version of RoleVoter and I've added the following to the resources.groovy file:

```
organizationRoleVoter(OrganizationRoleVoter)

accessDecisionManager(UnanimousBased) {
  decisionVoters = [organizationRoleVoter]
}
```

But Grails isn't using it.  No break points, no debug from my own class.  I'm assuming I just am not configuring it correctly.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found in the [spring-security-core docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/voters.html) how to do this.